# Mongodb $near ignoring $maxDistance

Tags: mongodb

I have two documents in a collection, like so:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5760fe623f6d3ad25e387ffc"),
  "type": 5,
  "product": {
    "location": {
      "geometry": [153.39999999999998, -28.016667],
      "name": "Gold Coast QLD, Australia",
      "id": "ChIJt2BdK0cakWsRcK_e81qjAgM"
    },
  }
}, {
  "_id": ObjectId("5761e1f5bc9e30306130ea5d"),
  "type": 5,
  "product": {
    "location": {
      "geometry": [153.60197700000003, -28.6473671],
      "name": "Byron Bay NSW 2481, Australia",
      "id": "ChIJK3Y-LYVikGsR0PJDkLQJBgQ"
    },
  }
}
```

When I run the following query, both documents are returned:

```
{ 
  'type': '5',
  'product.location.geometry': { 
     '$near': [ 153.39999999999998, -28.016667 ],
     '$maxDistance': 10000 
  } 
}
```

As you can see, I am querying the same long/lat as the first document in the collection. My `$maxDistance` is set to 10000m (10kms), yet it seems to be ignoring this. I jumped onto a long/lat calculator, and it seems as if those two locations are more than 72kms from eachother:

[image]

---

Why is my query ignoring my `$maxDistance` when the [docs clearly state](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) that `$maxDistance` must be in meters?

Comment: If you are using 2d index then `maxDistance` will accept distance in radians not in meters.

Comment: Ahhh yes you're right. My fault, TL;DR. Had to convert my KMs into Radians using the following formula: `kms/(earthRadius*pi/180)` which was `100/(6371*3.14159265359/180)`